# View query result

Tags: views

when i created view it shows the result and and the query in a preview
and here is the query

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language, 
node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_field_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.language IN  ('en')) AND (node.type IN  ('news')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

there is a field that hold the image value i think (field_data_field_image_node_entity_type)
but when i loop the result it does not display image value inspite it displayed in view result preview 
how am i get this value of image to display it rather than using views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views doesn't directly query every piece of that it needs to render data.

Some of the data is build on the pre_render hook.

The pre_render hook runs after the initial view query and is used to generate some of the missing data.

In drupal 7 views uses a pre_render hook for loading the fields via a entity_load and then field_get_items.

This is also common in the drupal 6 version of view. One good example is the Taxonomy get All terms. This is also build on the pre_render hook.

If you want to get this field without using view you can do this

```
$entity = entity_load('node', $nid);
$image_field = field_get_items('node', $entity, 'name_of_the_field');
```

The field you want is now in the $image_field variable.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely views is doing an entity load, to get the node and all of it's fields. You could do the same, for nodes you can do node_load($nid).